# Typeorm, SQL - Return multiple values from a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

I am using Typeorm in a Node.js project and I have encountered a problem which I am not sure I'm tackiling in a right way

Each campaign has many missions and each mission has many members. I want to display the average number of members across all missions per campaign, separately for those who started and those who completed

```js
const campaignStatistics = await this.campaignRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('campaign')
  .select(['campaign.id', 'campaign.title', 'campaign.dateFrom'])
  .where("campaign.status = 'active'")
  .addSelect(subQuery =>
    subQuery
      .select('CAST(AVG(participation_count) AS DECIMAL(5, 1)) AS "participationAverage"')
      .from(
        subQuery =>
          subQuery
            .select("COUNT(members.id) FILTER (WHERE missions.triggered = 'true' AND members.started = 'true')", 'participation_count')
            .from(CampaignEntity, 'campaign_sub')
            .where('campaign_sub.id = campaign.id')
            .leftJoin('campaign_sub.missions', 'missions')
            .leftJoin('missions.members', 'members')
            .groupBy('missions.id'),
        'participation_count'
      )
  )
  .addSelect(subQuery =>
    subQuery
      .select('CAST(AVG(completion_count) AS DECIMAL(5, 1)) AS "completionAverage"')
      .from(
        subQuery =>
          subQuery
            .select("COUNT(members.id) FILTER (WHERE missions.triggered = 'true' AND members.completed = 'true')", 'completion_count')
            .from(CampaignEntity, 'campaign_sub')
            .where('campaign_sub.id = campaign.id')
            .leftJoin('campaign_sub.missions', 'missions')
            .leftJoin('missions.members', 'members')
            .groupBy('missions.id'),
          'completion_count'
      )
  )
  .orderBy('campaign.dateFrom', 'DESC')
  .limit(3)
  .getRawAndEntities();
```

The typeorm query builder above is what I came up with. It does the job, achieving exactly what I need, but I am wondering if there is an option to concat these two subqueries. They are doing basically the same thing, with different values in WHERE clause.

After trying something like this:

```js
  .addSelect(subQuery =>
          subQuery
            .select([
              'CAST(AVG(participation_count) AS DECIMAL(5, 1)) AS "participationAverage"',
              'CAST(AVG(completion_count) AS DECIMAL(5, 1)) AS "completionAverage"'
            ])
            .from(
              subQuery =>
                subQuery
                  .select([
                    "COUNT(members.id) FILTER (WHERE missions.triggered = 'true' AND members.started = 'true') AS participation_count",
                    "COUNT(members.id) FILTER (WHERE missions.triggered = 'true' AND members.completed = 'true') AS completion_count"
                  ])
                  .from(CampaignEntity, 'campaign_sub')
                  .where('campaign_sub.id = campaign.id')
                  .leftJoin('campaign_sub.missions', 'missions')
                  .leftJoin('missions.members', 'members')
                  .groupBy('missions.id'),
              'count'
            )
        )
```

I receive `ERROR:  subquery must return only one column`

Is there a different approach to achieve the same result, while increasing the performance?

Here is the generated query, may be easier to work with that:

```sql
SELECT   "campaign"."id"        AS "campaign_id",
         "campaign"."title"     AS "campaign_title",
         "campaign"."date_from" AS "campaign_date_from",
         (
                SELECT Cast( Avg(participation_count) AS DECIMAL(5, 1) ) AS "participationAverage"
                FROM   (
                                 SELECT    Count("members"."id") filter ( WHERE "missions"."triggered" = 'true'
                                 AND       "members"."started" = 'true' ) AS "participation_count"
                                 FROM      "campaign" "campaign_sub"
                                 LEFT JOIN "mission" "missions"
                                 ON        "missions"."campaignId" = "campaign_sub"."id"
                                 LEFT JOIN "mission_member" "members"
                                 ON        "members"."missionId" = "missions"."id"
                                 WHERE     "campaign_sub"."id" = "campaign"."id"
                                 GROUP BY  "missions"."id" ) "participation_count" ),
         (
                SELECT Cast( Avg(completion_count) AS DECIMAL(5, 1) ) AS "completionAverage"
                FROM   (
                                 SELECT    Count("members"."id") FILTER ( WHERE "missions"."triggered" = 'true'
                                 AND       "members"."completed" = 'true' ) AS "completion_count"
                                 FROM      "campaign" "campaign_sub"
                                 LEFT JOIN "mission" "missions"
                                 ON        "missions"."campaignId" = "campaign_sub"."id"
                                 LEFT JOIN "mission_member" "members"
                                 ON        "members"."missionId" = "missions"."id"
                                 WHERE     "campaign_sub"."id" = "campaign"."id"
                                 GROUP BY  "missions"."id" ) "completion_count" )
FROM     "campaign" "campaign"
WHERE    "campaign"."status" = 'active'
ORDER BY "campaign"."date_from" DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: I recommend you improve this question by removing irrelevant information. reproducing bugs (undesirable behavior) with minimal code helps others help you. It also might help you find the answer yourself.